# Nginx virtual host does not work after erasing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, nginx, virtualhost

I had set up an nginx virtual host serving an angularjs SPA whose entry file is `index.html` on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS pc, working just fine.

After doing a format and installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, (and nginx ofcourse), I copied my virtual host file from /etc/nginx/sites-available folder which I had kept before formatting my PC, and remade the required symlink to sites-enabled/ folder. But it does not work (I am getting "This site can’t be reached" message by different browsers).

Syntax and status checks are ok. The default nginx page in port 80 is there. I have restarted nginx as well as my pc multiple times to exclude any weird caching scenarios.

I do `sudo ufw app list` and the results are (I guess) ok (CUPS, Nginx Full, Nginx HTTP, Nginx HTTPS).

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file is the following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {
  
  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;

  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;

  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
  application/javascript text/xml application/xml 
  application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

And my virtual host file inside sites-available folder is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /home/my_user/parent/file/path;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name my_server.local www.my_server.local;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

What might be going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Turns up I hadn't include the line:

```
127.0.0.1       my_server.local
```

in the `/etc/hosts` file, and that's why I was getting "This site can’t be reached" message on the browser. Alas, now I am getting **403 forbidden** message from Nginx. I tried changing the owner of the above server root path to `www-data` but I got the same message.

How do I solve that?

Comment: Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 22 are versions of Ubuntu Core. You have tagged Ubuntu 22.04. Please edit your question and make it clear what it is you are doing and asking.

Comment: I clarified that I am talking about switching from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my pc. Everything else I think is already clear: I was running an nginx virtual host, and after the upgrade the virtual host with the same setup is not working.

Comment: Your configs are incomplete.  Include your enabled site configs.  And explain "not working" in concrete terms - what type of site is it (PHP for example) and what is 'not working'?

Comment: @ThomasWard I added my enabled site config. But concerning the "not working" issue, what part of 'I am getting "This site can’t be reached" message by different browsers' that I write in my question do you think that needs explaining?

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias make sure nginx is in fact running.  Also run `sudo nginx -t` to see if there's any config errors.  If you have a firewall, make sure you allow ports 80 and 443.

Comment: @ThomasWard as I say in my question, syntax and status checks are ok. I am not sure how to check open ports, but if port 80 was closed, wouldn't I get somehting else than the nginx welcome message on localhost url?

Comment: Not if you aren't using `localhost` in the URL no.  You indicate a 403 forbidden.  Check the error logs - `/var/log/nginx/error.log` - and get the error information about the file paths NGINX is trying to access. Note that nginx should not be trying to read into the home directory or anywhere outside `/var/www` or its subdirectories for system security.

Comment: The ```error.log``` file says ```(13: Permission denied)```. Is it ok to put a symlink into a /var/www/ subdirectory pointing to my original file in ```/home/my_user/...``` and put the symlink as index in my virtual host config ?

Comment: @ThomasWard I solved the problem! Can the moderators allow me to post the answer for the community?

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias yes, but detail your answer and your solution exactly.  From a security perspective, symlinks are just as bad as pointing things at the home directory itself since you have to follow the symlink as well to get to the file and if those perms are not correct you still get the 403.  I've reopened the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the files ownership. At first I had changed the ownership to `www-data` user only at the last `/path` folder in `/home/my_user/parent/file/path`, but nginx demands that its user has ownership of the first ancestor directory of the path. Namely, when I did

```
sudo chown -R www-data:data /home/*
```

the `index.html` file in the last folder of the path was served normally.

But since I didn't want `my_user` to loose access to its files, I switched back the directory's ownership to `my_user` and I changed the nginx user, replacing the first line of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file with:

```
user my_user;
```

After that, `index.html` was served without any more problems.